# Using WindowsInstaller COM Reference with .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, com, windows-installer, com-interop

I'm working on a small application which installs through a Windows Installer package (.msi) made with WiX.
As requirements evolved, now the same program needs to be installed multiple times on the same computer with different configurations.
To solve this issue I tried writing a simple command line tool to update an existing .msi.

The tool is supposed to do three things programmatically:

1. set the `ProductName` in the `Property`-table
2. set the `UpgradeCode` in the `Upgrade`-table for the ActionProperties `NEWERFOUND`, `SELFFOUND` & `PREVIOUSFOUND`. (this is where I fail)
3. sign the msi again

Unfortunately. I have pretty much found no documentation or examples regarding similar implementations in .NET Core and therefore had to rely on examples implemented in partly outdated .NET Framework versions. The code to override the `UpgradeCode` looks as follows:

```
public void SetUpgradeCodes(string msiPath, string upgradeCode)
{
    var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
    
    var installer = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)Activator.CreateInstance(installerType);
    
    var db = installer.OpenDatabase(msiPath, MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeDirect);

    view = db.OpenView("SELECT * FROM Upgrade WHERE ActionProperty = 'NEWERFOUND' OR ActionProperty = 'SELFFOUND' OR ActionProperty = 'PREVIOUSFOUND'");
    view.Execute();
    
    for(var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        var record = view.Fetch();
        record.StringData[1] = upgradeCode;
        view.Modify(MsiViewModify.msiViewModifyReplace, record);
    }

    db.Commit();
    view.Close();

    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(view);
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(db);
}
```

The problem I encounter is that 'view.Modify(...)' always throws a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetIDispatchForObject(Object o)
   at System.RuntimeType.WrapArgsForInvokeCall(Object[] aArgs, Int32[] aArgsWrapperTypes)
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Object[] aArgs, Boolean[] aArgsIsByRef, Int32[] aArgsWrapperTypes, Type[] aArgsTypes, Type retType)
   at WindowsInstaller.View.Modify(MsiViewModify Mode, Record Record)
```

For the sake of completeness, the COM reference section in my .csproj lloks like this (I sincerely hope that I'm only missing some sort of configuration for the com reference or something like that):

```
<COMReference Include="WindowsInstaller">
  <Guid>{000C1092-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}</Guid>
  <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <Lcid>1033</Lcid>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
  <Isolated>False</Isolated>
</COMReference>
```

Is this COM Reference maybe not usable in .NET Core to full extends?
Updating the ProductName using the COM Reference works fine though.
What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Update your tooling so you can target .NET 5+

Comment: .net core shouldn't be a problem. I would recommend to give it a try using simpler approach first. e.g. a VB Script. This logic could be easily written in it.